# Difference between date and ISO date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just encountered two dates in JavaScript difference between date and ISO date. Can someone put some light on what is the difference between these two?

Comment: See here: http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MDN documentation has a good amount of information on the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

They have an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) on how to produce iso-8601 formatted dates.

Answer (score 8):

ISO stands for International Organization for Standardization. The ISO  standard organizes the data so the largest temporal term (the year) appears first in the data string and progresses to the smallest term. EX: 2011-07-14.

Javacript's getDate() function from the date object returns the day of the month(1-31). Javascript also has a few other functions you might want to use, such as:

```
var d = new Date();
d.getDay()
d.getFullYear()
d.getHours()
d.getMinutes()
d.getSeconds()
```

Good documentation is available here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

To sum it all up, ISO date is just a commonly used format for displaying the date.

Comment: Why the Downvote? I am pretty sure this information is correct.

Answer (score 1):

i found a online calculator for difference between two date timestamps
http://www.onlineconversion.com/days_between_advanced.htm
its their source code

```
var ts1='2020-02-10T08:07:29.058Z'
var ts2='2020-02-10T10:56:32.021Z'



function p (i)
{
return Math.floor(i / 10) + "" + i % 10;
}

function trunc (i)
{
var j = Math.round(i * 100);
return Math.floor(j / 100) + (j % 100 > 0 ? "." + p(j % 100) : "");
}

function calculate (ts1,ts2)
{
var date1 = new Date(ts1);
console.log(date1)
var date2 = new Date(ts2);
console.log(date2)

var sec = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
if (isNaN(sec))
{
    console.log("Input data is incorrect!");
    return;
}
if (sec < 0)
{
    console.log("The second date ocurred earlier than the first one!");
    return;
}

var second = 1000, minute = 60 * second, hour = 60 * minute, day = 24 * hour;

var inHour = trunc(sec / hour);
var inMin = trunc(sec / minute);
var inSec = trunc(sec / second);

var days = Math.floor(sec / day);
sec -= days * day;
var hours = Math.floor(sec / hour);
sec -= hours * hour;
var minutes = Math.floor(sec / minute);
sec -= minutes * minute;
var seconds = Math.floor(sec / second);
var inDays = days + " day" + (days != 1 ? "s" : "") + ", " + hours + " hour" + (hours 
!= 1 ? "s" : "") + ", " + minutes + " minute" + (minutes != 1 ? "s" : "") + ", " + 
seconds + " second" + (seconds != 1 ? "s" : "");
var duration =hours + " hour" + (hours != 1 ? "s" : "") + ", " + minutes + " minute" + 
(minutes != 1 ? "s" : "") + ", " + seconds + " second" + (seconds != 1 ? "s" : "");

console.log('in days ',inDays)
console.log('in days ',duration)
console.log('in hours ',inHour)
console.log('in mins ',inMin)
console.log('in secs ',inSec)
}

calculate(ts1,ts2)
```